# Annoying problems with struct in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, compiler-errors

My problem is that I don't know how to program things in c++ like I do in c#. So I don`t know what is the problem with my code.
 I'm trying to create two structs. One to represent a Matrix33 and the other a vector2d :

```
struct Vector2
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float h;

    Vector2()
    {
        x = y = h = 0;
    }
    Vector2(float valueX, float valueY, float valueH)
    {
        x = valueX;
        y = valueY;
        h = valueH;

    }
    Vector2(float valueX, float valueY)
    {
        x = valueX;
        y = valueY;
        h = 1;
    }


    Vector2 Translate(Vector2 dir)
    {
        Matrix33 matrix = Matrix33::GetIdentity();

        matrix.a02 = dir.x;
        matrix.a12 = dir.y;

        return matrix * Vector2(x, y, h);
    }

    static Vector2 VectorOne()
    {
        return Vector2(1, 1, 1);
    }
    static Vector2 VectorUP()
    {
        return Vector2(0, 1, 0);
    }
    static Vector2 VectorFoward()
    {
        return Vector2(0, 0, 1);
    }
    static Vector2 VectorRight()
    {
        return Vector2(1, 0, 0);
    }

    Vector2 operator*(const int value)
    {
        return Vector2(x*value, y*value, h);
    }
    Vector2 operator/(const int value)
    {
        return Vector2(x / value, y / value, 1);
    }
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2 value)
    {
        return  Vector2(x + value.x, y + value.y);
    }
    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2 value)
    {
        return  Vector2(x - value.x, y - value.y);
    }

};

struct Matrix33
{
    float a00; float a01; float a02;
    float a10; float a11; float a12;
    float a20; float a21; float a22;

    Matrix33()
    {
        a00 = a01 = a02 = a10 = a11 = a12 = a20 = a21 = a22 = 0;
    }
    void AddValues(int line, float c1, float c2, float c3)
    {
        if (line == 0)
        {
            a00 = c1;
            a01 = c2;
            a02 = c3;
        }
        else if (line == 1)
        {
            a10 = c1;
            a11 = c2;
            a12 = c3;
        }
        else if (line == 2)
        {
            a20 = c1;
            a21 = c2;
            a20 = c3;
        }
    }

    static Matrix33 GetIdentity()
    {
        Matrix33 m;
        m.a00 = m.a11 = m.a22 = 1;

        return m;
    }

    Matrix33 operator*(const Matrix33 m)
    {
        Matrix33 result;
        result.AddValues(0, (a00*m.a00 + a01*m.a10 + a02*m.a20), (a00*m.a01 + a01*m.a11 + a02*m.a21), (a00*m.a02 + a01*m.a12 + a02*m.a22));
        result.AddValues(1, (a10*m.a00 + a11*m.a10 + a12*m.a20), (a10*m.a01 + a11*m.a11 + a12*m.a21), (a10*m.a02 + a11*m.a12 + a12*m.a22));
        result.AddValues(2, (a20*m.a00 + a21*m.a10 + a22*m.a20), (a20*m.a01 + a21*m.a11 + a22*m.a21), (a20*m.a02 + a21*m.a12 + a22*m.a22));

        return result;
    }
    Vector2 operator*(const Vector2 p)
    {
        Vector2 result;

        result.x = a00*p.x + a01*p.y + a02*p.h;
        result.y = a10*p.x + a11*p.y + a12*p.h;
        result.h = a20*p.x + a21*p.y + a22*p.h;

        return result;
    }

};
```

The problem is that when I try to build I`m getting a lot of erros related to the my matrix aN values and the static func GetIdentity(). I have no idea of what is going on here.

> Error 7   error C2228: left of '.a12' must have class/struct/union
>   Error 16  error C2228: left of '.a12' must have class/struct/union
>   Error 27  error C2228: left of '.a12' must have class/struct/union
>   Error 5   error C2228: left of '.a02' must have class/struct/union
>   Error 14  error C2228: left of '.a02' must have class/struct/union
>   Error 25  error C2228: left of '.a02' must have class/struct/union
>
> Error 5   error C3861: 'GetIdentity': identifier not found
>   Error 16  error C3861: 'GetIdentity': identifier not found
>   Error 29  error C3861: 'GetIdentity': identifier not found
>   Error 4   error C2653: 'Matrix33' : is not a class or namespace name
>   Error 15  error C2653: 'Matrix33' : is not a class or namespace name
>   Error 28  error C2653: 'Matrix33' : is not a class or namespace name

Does anyone have some tips to help me here. I would appreciate a lot!.
Thanks

Comment: "My problem is that I don't know how to program things in c++ like I do in c#." And you shouldn't they're completely different languages.

Comment: well I thought at least the struct stuff was simillar some how.

Comment: Vector2 doesn't know about Matrix33 class, you need to forward declare or define Matrix33 before Vector2. I suggest some tutorial on C++ to start off.

Comment: `class` and `struct` are identical in C++ except that `class` members are private by default.

Comment: People will give you solutions but that won't fix the root cause, you need to learn C++ basics

Comment: You should learn about arrays.  Vectors and Matrices may be easier to implement using arrays and iteration loops (such as adding and multiplying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before defining any member function of class Vector2 that deals with elements of class Matrix3 you have to define class  Matrix3. And only after the definition of Matrix3 you may define these member functions of class Vector2.

For example

```
struct Vector2
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float h;

    Vector2()
    {
        x = y = h = 0;
    }
    Vector2(float valueX, float valueY, float valueH)
    {
        x = valueX;
        y = valueY;
        h = valueH;

    }
    Vector2(float valueX, float valueY)
    {
        x = valueX;
        y = valueY;
        h = 1;
    }

    // not defined but only declared    
    Vector2 Translate(Vector2 dir);

    // other members of the class
};


struct Matrix33
{
    float a00; float a01; float a02;
    float a10; float a11; float a12;
    float a20; float a21; float a22;

    Matrix33()
    {
        a00 = a01 = a02 = a10 = a11 = a12 = a20 = a21 = a22 = 0;
    }
    void AddValues(int line, float c1, float c2, float c3)
    {
        if (line == 0)
        {
            a00 = c1;
            a01 = c2;
            a02 = c3;
        }
        else if (line == 1)
        {
            a10 = c1;
            a11 = c2;
            a12 = c3;
        }
        else if (line == 2)
        {
            a20 = c1;
            a21 = c2;
            a20 = c3;
        }
    }

    static Matrix33 GetIdentity()
    {
        Matrix33 m;
        m.a00 = m.a11 = m.a22 = 1;

        return m;
    }

    Matrix33 operator*(const Matrix33 m)
    {
        Matrix33 result;
        result.AddValues(0, (a00*m.a00 + a01*m.a10 + a02*m.a20), (a00*m.a01 + a01*m.a11 + a02*m.a21), (a00*m.a02 + a01*m.a12 + a02*m.a22));
        result.AddValues(1, (a10*m.a00 + a11*m.a10 + a12*m.a20), (a10*m.a01 + a11*m.a11 + a12*m.a21), (a10*m.a02 + a11*m.a12 + a12*m.a22));
        result.AddValues(2, (a20*m.a00 + a21*m.a10 + a22*m.a20), (a20*m.a01 + a21*m.a11 + a22*m.a21), (a20*m.a02 + a21*m.a12 + a22*m.a22));

        return result;
    }
    Vector2 operator*(const Vector2 p)
    {
        Vector2 result;

        result.x = a00*p.x + a01*p.y + a02*p.h;
        result.y = a10*p.x + a11*p.y + a12*p.h;
        result.h = a20*p.x + a21*p.y + a22*p.h;

        return result;
    }

};

// now you may define it
Vector2 Vector2::Translate(Vector2 dir)
{
    Matrix33 matrix = Matrix33::GetIdentity();

    matrix.a02 = dir.x;
    matrix.a12 = dir.y;

    return matrix * Vector2(x, y, h);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to make many changes. You can forward declare `Vector2`, move the definition of `Vector2` after `Matrix33`, and then move the definition of your `operator*` outside of `Matrix33`. For example:

```
// Forward declaration
struct Vector2;

struct Matrix33
{
  // ...    
  Vector2 operator*(const Vector2 p); 
  // ^ declaration only because
  //   Vector2 is an incomplete type at this point
};

struct Vector2
{
 // ...
};

Vector2 Matrix33::operator*(const Vector2 p)
{
  Vector2 result;

  result.x = a00*p.x + a01*p.y + a02*p.h;
  result.y = a10*p.x + a11*p.y + a12*p.h;
  result.h = a20*p.x + a21*p.y + a22*p.h;

  return result;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a95fd4f28a9e0f7)

Comment: How does the last line you suggested Vector2 Matrix33::operator*(const Vector2 p) will get my a00,a01 etc values ?

Comment: since the code is outside the struct where thouse floats are defined